# copying data from one xml file to another xml file

Tags: xml, xslt

i have a source.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Studentdatabase>
    <Student>
        <id>0001</id>
        <Fname>SOMEX</Fname>
        <Mname>Y</Mname>
        <Lname>Z</Lname>
        <DOB>1992-05-26T00:00:00+05:30</DOB>
        <fathersname>XYZ</fathersname>
        <cls>I</cls>
        <gen>M</gen>
        <add>kadapa</add>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <id>0002</id>
        <Fname>SOMEA</Fname>
        <Mname>B</Mname>
        <Lname>C</Lname>
        <DOB>1991-04-6T00:00:00+05:30</DOB>
        <fathersname>ABC</fathersname>
        <cls>II</cls>
        <gen>F</gen>
        <add>PUNE</add>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <id>0003</id>
        <Fname>SOMED</Fname>
        <Mname>E</Mname>
        <Lname>F</Lname>
        <DOB>1990-08-2T00:00:00+05:30</DOB>
        <fathersname>DEF</fathersname>
        <cls>III</cls>
        <gen>M</gen>
        <add>JMD</add>
    </Student>
</Studentdatabase>
```

and a destination.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<MyDB>
  <tableName>
    <studentid>1</studentid>
    <Firstname>chaithanya</Firstname>
    <middlename>babu</middlename>
    <lastname>satyala</lastname>
    <Dateofbirth>1991-05-26T00:00:00+05:30</Dateofbirth>
    <fathersname>babu</fathersname>
    <class>I</class>
    <gender>M</gender>
    <address>kadapa</address>
  </tableName>
  <tableName>
    <studentid>2</studentid>
    <Firstname>charan</Firstname>
    <middlename>kumar</middlename>
    <lastname>palla</lastname>
    <Dateofbirth>1990-10-05T00:00:00+05:30</Dateofbirth>
    <fathersname>krishnaiah</fathersname>
    <class>I</class>
    <gender>M</gender>
    <address>hyderabad</address>
  </tableName>
  <tableName>
    <studentid>3</studentid>
    <Firstname>kondaiah</Firstname>
    <middlename />
    <lastname>dasari</lastname>
    <Dateofbirth>1985-06-05T00:00:00+05:30</Dateofbirth>
    <fathersname>dasari</fathersname>
    <class>II</class>
    <gender>M</gender>
    <address>porumamilla</address>
  </tableName>
  <tableName>
    <studentid>4</studentid>
    <Firstname>dheeraj</Firstname>
    <middlename>reddy</middlename>
    <lastname>polimera</lastname>
    <Dateofbirth>1991-05-16T00:00:00+05:30</Dateofbirth>
    <fathersname>krishna reddy</fathersname>
    <class>II</class>
    <gender>M</gender>
    <address>pulivendula</address>
  </tableName>
  <tableName>
    <studentid>5</studentid>
    <Firstname>shabaz</Firstname>
    <middlename>banu</middlename>
    <lastname>noormohammad</lastname>
    <Dateofbirth>1991-06-16T00:00:00+05:30</Dateofbirth>
    <fathersname>noor ahmed</fathersname>
    <class>III</class>
    <gender>F</gender>
    <address>jmd</address>
  </tableName>
  <tableName>
    <studentid>6</studentid>
    <Firstname>khairuna</Firstname>
    <middlename>begum</middlename>
    <lastname>taticherla</lastname>
    <Dateofbirth>2002-02-02T00:00:00+05:30</Dateofbirth>
    <fathersname>kullay</fathersname>
    <class>III</class>
    <gender>F</gender>
    <address>gugudu</address>
  </tableName>
  <tableName>
    <studentid>7</studentid>
    <Firstname>chandrakala</Firstname>
    <middlename />
    <lastname>kummera</lastname>
    <Dateofbirth>1991-06-03T00:00:00+05:30</Dateofbirth>
    <fathersname>lingreddy</fathersname>
    <class>IV</class>
    <gender>F</gender>
    <address>anantapur</address>
  </tableName>
</MyDB>
```

Now the issue is i need to insert the data from source file to destination file by changing the names of the elements and tags with reference to destination file... i.e., for example `<Fname>` in the source file must be changed to `<FirstName>` in destination file

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: What about the `studentid` element? In the destination document there is already `studentid` with value 1. In the source XML document there is also a `Student` with `id` `0001`. What is the rule to assign student ids?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to start off by reading about the XSLT [Identity Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform). This would just copy all elements as-is

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

In your case though, it looks like only the **fathersname** element is unchanging. You then need to write templates to match the elements you do want to change, and create new elements in their place. For example, to 'rename' the **Studentdatabase** to **MyDB** you would do the following:

```
<xsl:template match="Studentdatabase">
   <MyDB>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </MyDB>
</xsl:template>
```

And to change **Student** into **tableName** you would do the following:

```
<xsl:template match="Student">
   <tableName>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </tableName>
</xsl:template>
```

If you repeat this for all the elements you want to rename, you should be able to get your expected output.